# how to access data in RefClass

Tags: r

I am trying to extract data from a RefClass, and I am trying to turn it into a dataframe. Can someone explain how to do this? An explanation of Why someone would use a RefClass instead of a dataframe would be awesome as well.

```
s <- searchTwitter('#United')
str(s[1])
getRefClass("status")

#console output
> str(s[1])
List of 1
 $ :Reference class 'status' [package "twitteR"] with 17 fields
  ..$ text         : chr "#Waterbury #united #earringswag #twitteraddict Import #and #profit. #the complete guide to importing goods: How T http://t.co/D"| __truncated__
  ..$ favorited    : logi FALSE
  ..$ favoriteCount: num 0
  ..$ replyToSN    : chr(0) 
  ..$ created      : POSIXct[1:1], format: "2015-09-13 05:11:48"
  ..$ truncated    : logi FALSE
  ..$ replyToSID   : chr(0) 
  ..$ id           : chr "642928643795058688"
  ..$ replyToUID   : chr(0) 
  ..$ statusSource : chr "<a href=\"http://twitterfeed.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">twitterfeed</a>"
  ..$ screenName   : chr "ArielKaylee1"
  ..$ retweetCount : num 0
  ..$ isRetweet    : logi FALSE
  ..$ retweeted    : logi FALSE
  ..$ longitude    : chr(0) 
  ..$ latitude     : chr(0) 
  ..$ urls         :'data.frame':   1 obs. of  5 variables:
  .. ..$ url         : chr "http://t.co/D2kr0RzecR"
  .. ..$ expanded_url: chr "http://bit.ly/1UM4xF0"
  .. ..$ display_url : chr "bit.ly/1UM4xF0"
  .. ..$ start_index : num 114
  .. ..$ stop_index  : num 136
  ..and 53 methods, of which 39 are  possibly relevant:
  ..  getCreated, getFavoriteCount, getFavorited, getId, getIsRetweet, getLatitude, getLongitude, getReplyToSID, getReplyToSN, getReplyToUID, getRetweetCount,
  ..  getRetweeted, getRetweeters, getRetweets, getScreenName, getStatusSource, getText, getTruncated, getUrls, initialize, setCreated, setFavoriteCount, setFavorited,
  ..  setId, setIsRetweet, setLatitude, setLongitude, setReplyToSID, setReplyToSN, setReplyToUID, setRetweetCount, setRetweeted, setScreenName, setStatusSource,
  ..  setText, setTruncated, setUrls, toDataFrame, toDataFrame#twitterObj
>
```

Comment: What would the resulting data.frame look like?

Comment: Maybe you want to use the method `s$toDataFrame()` ?

Comment: I am just trying to figure out how to pull any of the column data into a dataframe. I tried `s$toDataFrame()` no luck I got `Error: attempt to apply non-function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the answer by using:

```
> df<-NULL
> df <- sapply(s, function(x) x$toDataFrame())
```